# AppleScript to find and replace in a folder of text files

Tags: applescript

I need to replace text in a folder full of text files. How would I go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tell application "Finder"
    set l to files of desktop as alias list
end tell
repeat with f in l
    set input to read f as «class utf8»
    set text item delimiters to "search"
    set ti to text items of input
    set text item delimiters to "replace"
    set b to open for access f with write permission
    set eof b to 0
    write (ti as text) to b as «class utf8»
    close access b
end repeat
```

I mostly just use find in project in TextMate or Ruby scripts like this:

```
Dir["#{ENV['HOME']}/Desktop/*"].each do |f|
  input = File.read(f).gsub(/search/, "replace")
  File.open(f, "w") { |f| f.print(input) }
end
```

You could also use sed:

```
sed -i '' 's/search/replace/g' ~/Desktop/*
```